# (Unity 3D C#) Conveyor Physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, i am trying to create a flat conveyor that a block will sit on and move, but i want to have it be able to turn, so i cant use rigidbody.moveposition, ive tried using addforce, but i cant get it to work properly without using impule or velocity change, because then it makes the ore roll (they are cubes). my most recent attempt was using velocity, but im not sure how to make it keep its old velocity when changing corners so it doesnt screw it up.

.

If this doesn't make much sense, here is a better explanation, i am trying to create a conveyor system on a grid, where each slot has a direction, and an cube travels along it, whenever the cube reaches a turn, i want the cube to keep moving forward a short distance so it doesn't just immediately change directions and go along the new conveyor, because this way, it will immediately change and will sit on the edge of the conveyor, and not keep moving in the direction.

edit: i currently have it working, my now issue is the cubes will bounce when touching the conveyor, so they wont stay flat against the conveyor, i can fix this by constricting all the cube rotation, but then it will sometimes freeze the ore on the conveyor, not allowing it to move.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide code, I don't know what you are trying to do, so I will give my own solution:

```
object.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(target.transform.position, endpoint.position, Time.deltaTime * speed)
```

Then, when it collides with it, it can turn off this script, so it stays at the end.

`target` is what you want to move, `endpoint` is where you want it to end up.

Make endpoint a gameObject, and put it at the end of your conveyor, so the objects will move toward, and it will look like a conveyer.